# Trigger Visibility change before it is successfully applied

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the style for one of my user controls:

```
<Style x:Key="AddServerPanel" TargetType="{x:Type uc:AddServer}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="252,550,26,0" To="252,248,26,0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="252,248,26,0" To="252,550,26,0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have a user control hidden in the background appearing when I click on the button. I want to have a slide in and slide out animation. This code already works for sliding in but sliding out doesn't works properly as the control just disappears. I think this is because the visibility property is applied to the control and afterwards the trigger is called. How could I fix this behaviour to have a proper "slide out" effect on the control?

**Edit**

I changed my code and switched over to a DataTrigger. 
However this is working but I just see the animation when the Binding property value is false. This is really curious.
Also it would be nice to know how the set the "From" property in the ThicknessAnimation to the current margin of the control.

```
<uc:AddServer x:Name="AddServerPanel" Height="300" Width="570" Margin="252,550,26,0">
    <uc:AddServer.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AddServerPanelVisible}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:2" From="252,550,26,0" To="252,248,26,0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AddServerPanelVisible}" Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:2" From="252,248,26,0" To="252,550,26,0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </uc:AddServer.Style>
</uc:AddServer>
```

Comment: how are you changing the Visibility of control?

Comment: Threw a binding with a ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using animations to show/hide the control, chances are you are manipulating the opacity of said control. If that's the case, you can begin your Storyboard in code, and, when completed, set visibility flag to true. This will run animation first, then set the visibility.

HOWEVER. I should point out that because you are already hiding the control via opacity, there's no real need to change it's visibility at that point.

Another option would be to set a visibility flag (that doesn't bind to the control's visibility property), and when flag value changes, start appropriate Storyboard (e.g., if flag is true, show control, or begin show animation).

I also wanted to explain why what you currently have does what it does.

Whenever you set a trigger, you are telling the control to do something when a property equals such and such value. What happens is the control is first hiding, and when visibility is hidden, only then will it start the hiding animation. Only problem is...it's already hidden! That's where my solution comes in ;)

**Edit**

Realized your animating margin, not opacity. In either case, the control is always hidden before beginning the animation, which is the problem.

**Solution**

Here's an example:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <!-- Fade in animation -->
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <!-- Fade out animation -->
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

`IsVisible` is a flag you'd have to define. The rest is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Well I changed the way how to manage it. I edited my initial post and still have a problem. Maybe you have a clue how to fix that.